# Strange error during debugging program with threads: Unable open /proc file

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb, procfs

During debugging a program with threads, I have a strange error:

```
(gdb) info threads 
warning: unable to open /proc file '/proc/3663/status'
warning: Can't attach LWP 3663: No child processes
Cannot find new threads: debugger service failed
```

I get no other warnings during the debug session.

The process/thread 3663 doesn't exist.

How can it be that the gdb misunderstands the pid of the process/thread?
What additional checks could I do to localize the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason of the failure.

The process I wanted to debug was in a process namespace; and the debugger was out of it.
When I started the debugger in the same namespace the problem gone away.

Comment: What do you mean "process namespace"?

Comment: Exactly, what do you mean by "process namespace"? I am hit with the same scenario, but not able to guess how you solved it.

Comment: @Wivlaro: If you don't know what that is, you probably do not need it at all. But if you really want it: http://www.haifux.org/lectures/299/netLec7.pdf

Comment: @Sandeep: See the previous comment

Comment: @IgorChubin Can you elaborate on how you start the debugger in the same namespace?

Comment: @Wivlaro: You must run tmux/screen in the namespace first, than start your process, and then open another terminal in screen and start the debugger in it